# Operator overload taking void

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a case in my code where I want to call a class-defined binary operator overload through a template, but the second argument might be type void. Is it possible to write that specialisation?

The why:

So I have a piece of existing macroisation/template wrapping which helps me log return values from functions.

It goes a bit like this:

```
#define Return  return DebugPlacement({__FILE__,__LINE__}) <<=
```

Where DebugPlacement is a little spot-class that has a templated overload for `operator <<=`

```
struct DebugPlacement
{
   const char* path; int line;

   template <class Arg>
   const Arg& operator <<= (const Arg& arg)const
   {
       std::cerr << "DIAG: " << path << ":" << line << " returns " << arg << std::endl;
       return arg;
   }

};
```

We chose operator <<= because it is pretty obscure and behaves somewhat like the existing streaming operator, but in reverse. Also its low precedence means that almost any sensible expression can be written on the RHS.

Another compromise: All the types are generally simple so use of rvals was not a big issue. I'm sure we will eventually see a need for perfect forwarding here, but not yet.

It prints the value, and returns it. And I can plug in various general specialisations as I find I need them, - char*, etc. No extra brackets are required. It works very nicely, thanks for asking!

In a lot of cases it is used in API stubs:

```
extern int MyFunction(int (arg1), int (arg2));
int MyFunctionStub(int (arg1), int (arg2))
{
  Return MyFunction(int (arg1), int (arg2));
}
```

And that stub behaviour, in turn, has ended up macroised. I know - it is a curse and a blessing. Needless to say, our usecases are not quite this trivial. The stub does also have work to do, so can't be eliminated or templated away. The names of the stubs are also historically fixed as the public "C" API.

But it all falls apart if the return type is void!

It appears the nice c++ gods think the following is acceptable, probably because of template wrappers needing to blindly forward return types:

```
extern void MyVFunction(int (arg1), int (arg2));
void MyVFunctionStub(int (arg1), int (arg2))
{
  return MyVFunction(int (arg1), int (arg2));
}
```

But with the macro substitution I can't add my tracing. They don't like:

```
extern void MyVFunction(int (arg1), int (arg2));
void MyVFunctionStub(int (arg1), int (arg2))
{
  return DebugPlacement({__FILE__,__LINE__}) <<= MyVFunction(int (arg1), int (arg2));
}

Errors (at the call-site):
 error: no viable overloaded '<<='
 note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = void]: cannot form a reference to 'void'
```

So is there some form of words to declare a specialisation of a binary operator that does require a right hand side, but of type void? Currently we are still living in a c++11 land. Am I going to have to wait for a later c++ standard, or are the standardisation gods not looking kindly upon me this time?

Of course, I have tried a few things:

```
template <>
auto DebugPlacement::operator <<=(void& t)const -> void&
error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
```

Also

```
    void operator <<=(void t)const 
error: argument may not have 'void' type
```

Comment: In `DebugPlacement({__FILE__,__LINE__}) <<= MyVFunction(int (arg1), int (arg2))`, where `MyVFunction()` returns `void`, what are you expecting `DebugPlacement` to log exactly, even if you could define a `<<=` operator for it? You will likely have to wrap the `MyVFunction()` call inside a functor, and then overload `operator<<=` for that functor, then the overload can decide what to do depending on whether the functor returns `void` or not.

Comment: `void` is an incomplete type have a read of [Void type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Void_type)

Comment: There is no such thing as 'type void', only 'type void *'

Comment: don't get the need for the operator overload ? can't it be just a function call? but in this case I could you override your operator with zero args?

Comment: @mohRamadan But then I would have to add brackets, which return statements don't have. Not a big price to pay, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: @Paul And yet, we can write a void function that can return the "value" of another void function. Syntactically the void type exists.

Comment: @Remy No, indeed it can't say much, but when used in a generic manner, it doesn't need to say much, just "survive". Perhaps all it can do is print the file position and function name, and that it returned rather than exception. That can still be useful if tracing a call stack flow. There are also internal error states.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a case in my code where I want to call a class-defined binary operator overload through a template, but the second argument might be type void. Is it possible to write that specialisation?

You can handle `void` return type using built-in binary [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator):

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, **it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression**), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2` begins **(note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing) (until C++17)**.

When its right-hand operand is `void` comma operator evaluates to `void`. Comma operator can be overloaded only for non-void operands. When any operand is `void` only the built-in comma operator is invoked, the user-defined `operator,` is not considered.

Comma operator [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is the lowest which is ideal for your task.

Note that [comma symbol (`,`) has different meanings in different contexts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator):

> The comma in various comma-separated lists, such as function argument lists (`f(a, b, c)`) and initializer lists `int a[] = {1, 2, 3}`, is not the comma operator. If the comma operator needs to be used in such contexts, it has to be parenthesized: `f(a, (n++, n + b), c)`.

C++11 example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct ReturnValueLogger {
    char const* file_;
    int const line_;

    std::ostream& log_file_line() const {
        return std::clog << file_ << ":" << line_ << ' ';
    }

    ReturnValueLogger(ReturnValueLogger const&) = delete;

    ~ReturnValueLogger() {
        if(file_) // operator, overload is not called for void rhs.
            log_file_line() << "Return value is void\n";
    }

    template<class T>
    auto operator,(T&& rhs) -> decltype(std::forward<T>(rhs)) { // Not called for void rhs.
        log_file_line() << "Return value is " << rhs << '\n';
        file_ = 0;
        return std::forward<T>(rhs);
    }
};

#define Return return ReturnValueLogger{__FILE__,__LINE__},

int  f() { return 1; }
void g() {}

int  f2() { Return f(); } // Outputs "Return value is 1".
void g2() { Return g(); } // Outputs "Return value is void".

int main() {
    f2();
    g2();
}
```

Overloading comma operator is also useful for a similar macro `Throw` to instrument exceptions with stacktrace, file and line information at throw sites.

Comment: A valuable opportunity to overload the comma operator. (I always asked myself for a use case with sense...) ;-)

Comment: Oh! I didn't even realise you could overload the comma operator, perhaps you couldn't last century? But it does do exactly what I want! And it is the lowest precedence, even better!

Comment: Thanks Max. Ah I see from your comment, when the RHS is void, actually the operator overload does not get called. So the momentary ReturnValueLogger object just falls out of scope, and the default behaviour of the comma means the void is returned. If you really want to log this you could detect that the logger object was destructed without having run the operator. It would be good to add that to the answer as clearer text for future reader clarity? I know it is there, but just in the code really.

Comment: I guess my only worry about overloading comma and the logical operators in general is that the default behaviour has documented ordering and short-circuit evaluation behaviours which are difficult/impossible in the overloaded methods.

Comment: Possible issue: In the void case, could the object destruct and print BEFORE the comma, and before the chained function (that does all the work) is called? I'll have a read up on the standard's guarantees around this, because again c++11 has more to say about lifetimes than the earlier versions.

Comment: I'm non-the-wiser having read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Full-expressions Which is referenced from "All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the _full-expression_ that (lexically) contains the point where they were created"

Comment: @GemTaylor Comma operator always evaluates both operands, `lhs` first, then `rhs`, no short-curcuiting there. The temporary `ReturnValueLogger` gets destroyed at the end of evaluation of the full expression. `;` marks the end of an expression, making it full and turning it into a statement. None of this has changed since C++98. C++17 added sequencing of operands for overloaded comma operator, but this use case is invariant with respect to operand sequencing.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I believe you. In the bad old days, I think some compilers had comma as a sequence point, and there is still a special case for array initialisation. Certainly it is giving the expected result, but that is no guarantee of standards correctness :-).

Comment: @GemTaylor IIRC, Microsoft compiler had a few bugs in temporary object lifetimes and references binding to them. That made me switch to Linux in 2003 and I never looked back.

Comment: @GemTaylor Note that comma has different meanings in different contexts, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator. Comma operator doesn't apply to initializer lists and function calls.